# Grav 1.7 Appi theme - how to apply an image to a module's expected image?

Tags: grav

I have Grav with a modular page:

`user/pages/03.mod (type: modular)`

Within that, I've added the Appi theme's module "herohome":

`user/pages/03.mod/_hero (type: modular/herohome)`

I want to add the background image to that herohome module.

In `herohome.html.twig` I can see `backgroundImage.jpg` as the html variable

```
{% if page.header.background_image %}
    {% set backgroundImage = 'background-image: url(' ~ page.media.images[page.header.background_image].url() ~ ');' %}
{% else %}
    {% set backgroundImage = '' %}
{% endif %}
```

So I've taken their supplied herohome.jpg screenshot, renamed it to backgroundImage, and uploaded that to Page Media.

I've inserted it into the body.

`![backgroundImage](backgroundImage.jpg "backgroundImage")`

Both the `03.mod` page and `_hero` module are published.

When I go to view the page, I can see the hero module there but the image is missing.

How do I apply the image? I can't see it in their docs/Google/YouTube.

Comment: If the answer of @Hun-Tran does solve your issue, please mark it as 'answer'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to insert image in your Markdown file's content as well as rename it to `backgroundImage.jpg`

You only need to upload your image to the modular page `_hero`, then set the `backgroundImage` field in your Markdown page's header, if `bg.jpg` is the file you upload the code will be:

```
background_image: bg.jpg
```

You can check the skeleton as an example. `bg.jpg` is used as the background image, it is uploaded to the modular page: https://github.com/tranduyhung/grav-skeleton-appi/tree/master/pages/01.home/_herohome. `background_image: bg.jpg` is added to the header

```
---
title: Video
background_image: bg.jpg
video_mp4: user/pages/01.home/_herohome/bg.mp4
heading: Your App. <span>Reinvented.</span>
subheading: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the <br class="hidden-xs">printing and typesetting industry.
buttons:
    -
        icon: icon-append-iphone
        text: Learn More
        url: '#'
---
```

(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tranduyhung/grav-skeleton-appi/master/pages/01.home/_herohome/herohome.md)

Comment: If you use Admin plugin, you can select the background image via `Background image` field, you don't need to edit the Markdown code manually.